# Client JS for Infinispan does not find cache entered by Infinispan Java client

Tags: javascript, node.js, infinispan, hot-rod

I've a application java to resposible to putting information in the caches and an application NodeJS responsible to manager the evict. The Infinispan Javascript client does not find the entries that was put by the Infinispan Java client. I tried to use the data types and string key's but it didn't work.

I'm use Infinispan 8.2 with Hot Rod protocol.

Answer (score 0):

For data types to work, the Java client also needs to provide data type information using the encoder (see [here](http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/user_guide/user_guide.html#data_encoding)), but that was only added in Infinispan 9.1.

An example showing how Infinispan endpoints can interop can be found [here](https://github.com/infinispan-demos/endpoint-interop). The example does not show the Node.js client, but once you've seen the types provided by the Java client, you should be able to use those data types with the Node.js client.